# The problem that screen enlargement when keyboard input in webView is left as it is

Tags: swift

We are currently developing an application using a web view with swift. Therefore, when you select a text field or list displayed in webvView, the selected text field or list is enlarged and a keyboard is an output on the screen, but after completing input with the keyboard, it remains in the enlarged display. I will.
I want to return to the original screen size from keyboard output expansion. How do I solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please read guide on how to ask a good question on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This will help you get better answers, because people will have more information about you problem.

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following (adjust the code according to your needs):

```swift
    // Call this when viewcontroller with webview is loaded, e.g. viewDidLoad
    // This will add an event listener to the keyboard hide event
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide , object: nil)

    // This is the event handler for when keyboard is hidden, place it inside your viewcontroller
    func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        // Revert to minimal scale
        myWebView.scrollView.zoomScale = myWebView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale
    }
```

Of course this will fire every time a keyboard is closed on that viewcontroller, so if there is something other than the webview on there, you will need to adjust the code to ignore events not coming from the webview keyboard by some means :-)